# Python - SQL UPDATE not updating every row

Tags: python, sql

```
cur.execute("""SELECT match_own_goals.game_id, home_team, away_team, team, time FROM football.match_own_goals JOIN football.match_info ON match_own_goals.game_id = match_info.game_id""")
e = cur.fetchall()

for game in e:
        print game
        time = game[4]
        if game[3] == 1:
            team_id = game[1]
        else:
            team_id = game[2]
        cur.execute("""UPDATE football.match_own_goals SET team_id = %s WHERE game_id = %s AND time = %s""", (team_id, game[0], time))
        db.commit()
```

Out of the 108 rows this should be updating it has only updated about 10, I have no idea why this might be.  It extracts all the information in the SELECT statement.  It is probably obvious but it is late haha.

Team is either 1 or 2, originally meant to signify home or away

Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing that this is a remote database... Have you made sure that your connection was not severed ?

Comment: hi, this db is local at the moment

Comment: How do you know it's not updating them? Could it be that its setting team_id to team_id?

Comment: because they are all still 0 in the db for the un updated games

Comment: @user2073606 that would certainly do it :)

Comment: You could probably do the entire thing in SQL, using `CASE WHEN ...` :)

Comment: Did you mean to do this: `...time = %s""", (team_id, game[0], time)` and not `...time = %s""" % (team_id, game[0], time)` ?

Comment: Only thimng I can think of then is it's messing up time somehow. If you print the sql you might see it's messing up the format in the convert to string for time = %s perhaps

Comment: Other ideas maybe just make sure `time = game[4]` as `time = str(game[4])`

Comment: I am a noob, what do you mean print the sql.  It is definately a problem with the time.  I deleted that section of the update and it populated perfectly

Comment: hi gabeio I tried that and it didn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

The query is:

```
UPDATE football.match_own_goals
    SET team_id = %s
    WHERE game_id = %s AND time = %s
```

If this is working *sometimes*, then the query is syntactically correct and your are connected to the database.

What is happening is that the selected rows are not what you expect.  So, run this query to see what should be updated:

```
select *
from football.match_own_goals
WHERE game_id = %s AND time = %s
```

One of the two fields is causing a problem with the comparison.

My guess is that the time field is the problem.  Times can be quite precise, more precise than what gets printed to user output.  For instance, perhaps the times are maintained to 1/10 of a second, but the time is printed out only to the second.  Only about 1/10 of the rows would really match an exact match.